# How to further speed site loading time for a static page?

Tags: html, css, optimization

Site [URL](https://deluxe-raindrop-40829a.netlify.app)

**Problem**:

I've deployed a static page to Netlify (that uses a CDN). Often I'll see that the text loads first, followed by the background image and fonts loading next. This creates a jarring transition. It becomes very obvious when using a slower connection (say 3G on a mobile device).

Is there a way to ensure all components (styled text, background image) are rendered at the same time or quicker so that the user doesn't experience the brief moment where the white text is seen on a white background, followed by change in the font, followed by the background image loading, followed by bootstrap 5 loading.

Steps taken so far to optimize the site:

1. Reduced the background image and size, including providing two sizes for the browser to pick from (srcset).
2. Self hosted fonts instead of CDN calls.
3. Preloading of css files and fonts.

What else can be done:

1. Remove bootstrap and replace it with something even lighter.

Answer (score 0):

The performance metrics in Lighthouse are good ( 93 score in performance ) though it recommends that you

- Ensure text remains visible during webfont load using the `font-display` property.
- Avoid the use of `document.write()`

That said to fix the issue of white background, specify default `background-color` so that the text is always visible regardless of how slow the client internet speed is.

As for the bootstrap, you are not really leveraging the feature set provided by bootstrap in your site, You can either make your css or extract the styles that you are using from bootstrap ( it can become a hassle for maintaining the project ).

Minify the `style.css` as well

All things considered, there will always be users with super-slow internet speeds. You can only optimize soo much.